# for loop usage in verilog test bench...stuck in a loop...need to know my mistake

Tags: verilog

I wrote the following code in verilog to generate test cases for my design, but there is a problem with the code and I am getting weird test cases. I need to get a total of 16 different cases with the 2 loops I wrote but I am able to get only 4 test cases. My "i" in the loop is iterating only once but it has to iterate for 4 times. The i am getting only 00 for A but for B I am able to get all the values "00" "01" "10" "11" ... can some one point the mistake I made?

```
// test generation
initial begin  
  for(i=2'b00;i<=2'b11;i=i+2'b01) begin 
    for(j=2'b00;j<=2'b11;j=j+2'b01) begin 
      if(i==2'b00) begin    
        #30  A=i;  B=j;
      end 
      else begin 
        #20  A=i;  B=j;
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are declaring `i` and `j` something like this:

```
reg [1:0] i, j;
```

And that your test doesn't terminate on its own (ie, you have to stop the simulation yourself). This is because if you look how the variable `j` is defined, it can only take on the values 2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b11. Your loop termination condition for the inner loop is that `j <= 2'b11`. However, this is ALWAYS true as the most `j` can ever be is 2'b11 and adding 2'b01 to 2'b11 yields 2'b00 for 2-bit vectors. Thus, the inner loop is infinite and never lets the outer loop progress. Similarly, if the inner loop was fixed, the outer loop would have the same problem.

There are a number of possible solutions to this, but the easiest is just making `i` and `j` 3-bit vectors instead of two. If you want to be precise, you can set `A` and `B` like so:

```
A = i[1:0];
B = j[1:0];
```